# Issue with uploading .csv file in PHP

Tags: php, email, file-upload, csv

Hey guys I have a function that will upload a .csv file.  Now what happens is companys would come and upload a csv file with thousands of employees.  Now I am having an issue with this though.  I keep getting:

Internal Error with the PCI, the max execution time and the files uploaded.

I took this to our provider Winhost and they raised it to 600 seconds - 10 minutes.  Now evan after doing this I still have trouble with it.  The same timeout message and everything.  So I don't know if it is not kicking out or what is going on but I really need some help on this one.

Code:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
header("location:/PCG/mainlogin.php");
}
require_once "Mail.php";
$hostname="";
$username="";
$password="";
$database="";

if (!empty($_POST['name'])){
$member = $_POST['name'];
$memval = 1;
}
function returnBack(){

    header("Location:PCG/csvuploaderform.php?seterror=1");
    exit;

}
function returnBackfile(){

    header("Location:PCG/csvuploaderform.php?seterror=2");
    exit;

}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    /*******************************CHECK TO MAKE SURE FORM IS PROPERLY FILLED AND GET NAME OF COLUMNS IN CSV FILE *********************************************************/

    if (!empty($_FILES['file']['error'] ) )
    {

        echo "file";
        $seterror =1;
        returnBack();

    } 
    if (empty($_POST['firstname'])){

        $seterror =1;
        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['lastname'])){
        $seterrro =1;

        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['email'])){
        $seterror =1;

        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['phone'])){
        $seterror =1;
        returnBack();
    }
    if ($seterror != 1){

    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];    

    $handle = fopen($file , "r");

    $fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",");

    $fileop=array_map("strtoupper",array_map("trim",$fileop));

    $firstname_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST["firstname"]),$fileop);
    if ($firstname_index===false){
        returnBack();
    }
    $lastname_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST['lastname']),$fileop);
    if ($lastname_index===false){

        returnBack();
    }
    $email_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST['email']),$fileop);
    if ($email_index===false){

        returnBack();
    }
    $phone_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST['phone']),$fileop);
    if ($phone_index===false){

        returnBack();
    }
    $date = date("Y-m-d");  
    /***********************ASSIGN COLUMN VALUES TO ACCORDING VARIABLES AND INSERT THEM INTO CSV TABLE IN DB *************************************/
    try {  
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    }  
    catch(PDOException $e) { 
        echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
    }
    /*$fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")*/
    if ($memval != 1){
    $memberview = $_SESSION['myusername'];
    }
    else{
        $sql ="SELECT username FROM members WHERE companyname =:companyname";
    $sth=$DBH->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(':companyname' => $member));

    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $check = $row;
    $memberview = $check['username'];
    }
    }
    $j = 0;
    while (($fileop=fgetcsv($handle)) !== false)
    {

        $fileop=array_map("trim",$fileop);

        $firstname[$j] = $fileop[$firstname_index];
        if (empty($firstname[$j])){ 
        returnBackfile();

        }

        $lastname[$j] = $fileop[$lastname_index];
            if (empty($lastname[$j])){
        returnBackfile();

        }
        $email[$j] = $fileop[$email_index];
            if (empty($email[$j])){

        returnBackfile();


        }
        $phone[$j] = $fileop[$phone_index];
            if (empty($phone[$j])){

        returnBackfile();   


        }
        $csvusername[$j] = $firstname[$j] . $lastname[$j];

        $csvpasswordname[$j] = $lastname[$j] . $firstname[$j];

        $status = "Open";

        $sql ="SELECT username FROM csvdata WHERE username =:csvusername";
        $sth=$DBH->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array(':csvusername' => $csvusername[$j]));

        while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $csvusername[$j] = $firstname[$j] . $lastname[$j] . rand(1,20);


        }

        $sql ="SELECT password FROM csvdata WHERE password =:csvpasswordname";
        $sth=$DBH->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array(':csvpasswordname' => $csvpasswordname[$j]));

        while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $csvpasswordname[$j] = $lastname[$j] . $firstname[$j] . rand(1,20);


        }

        $j++;
    }

        for($i =0; $i<$j; $i++){

        $sth = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO csvdata (firstname, lastname, email, phone, username, password, status, memberview, statuschangedate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
        $sth->execute(array($firstname[$i], $lastname[$i], $email[$i], $phone[$i], $csvusername[$i], $csvpasswordname[$i], $status, $memberview, $date));

        $from = "email.com";  
    $to = $email[$i]; 
    $subject = ""; 
    $body = "message.....";
$host = ""; 
$username = ""; 
$password = ""; 
$headers = array ('From' => $from, 
  'To' => $to, 
  'Subject' => $subject); 
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', 
  array ('host' => $host, 
  'auth' => true, 
  'username' => $username, 
  'password' => $password)); 
    //$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body); 

    }

    $email = "";
    $from = "";  
    $to = $email; 
    $subject = ""; 
    $body = ",



";
    $host = ""; 
$username = ""; 
$password = ""; 
$headers = array ('From' => $from, 
  'To' => $to, 
  'Subject' => $subject); 
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', 
  array ('host' => $host, 
  'auth' => true, 
  'username' => $username, 
  'password' => $password)); 
//$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
 header("Location:PCG/memberinterface.php?getmsg=11");
 exit;
    }
}
    $DBH = null;
```

so if there is anything you see wrong please let me know!  Something is wrong and I need to figure it out!

David,

Thank you!

UPDATE:

Okay guys after looking at it and stopping the email function from sending I noticed that it worked really really fast.  So how do I speed up this email sending or keep it from keeping the page running so long?

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini

set the following

```
max_execution_time = 300
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```